# Ошибка при update таблицы из jsf страницы

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee

Здравствуйте. 
Пытаюсь сделать update:

```
    public void updateSubcategory(Subcategory subcategory) {

    if(subcategory == null) return;

    Query query = getSession().createQuery("update Subcategory set name = :name where id = :id");

    query.setParameter("name", subcategory.getName());
    query.setParameter("id", subcategory.getId());

    int result = query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Ругается на строку: `Query query = getSession().createQuery("update Subcategory set name = :name where id = :id");`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

Делаю аналогично delete, с delete всё работает, а с update какая-то беда...

Answer (score 1):

пробуй так:

```
String sql= String.format("UPDATE Subcategory set name =%s where id = %s", subcategory.getName(), subcategory.getId());
Query query= session.createSQLQuery(sql);
```